# Codeigniter: How to load the url with this AJAX Template?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I bought a template and I am making it dynamic. I have an issue and I am not sure how to go around it. 
This is how the template html work. When you click on 'About Us' for example and on the right hand side the about us page is loaded and in the URL there is #!about segment and if you click 'Contacts' it will be the same.

Obviously when I am using Codeigniter and when I am trying to do the same thing it is searching for controller named 'about'.

Any idea how to get around it ?

This is the function:

```
   * AJAX PAGE LOADING */

    function loadcontent() {
    "use strict"; 
    $("#right-column").find("#page-box").removeClass('fadeInDownBig').addClass('fadeOutRightBig');
        setTimeout(function () { $("body").find('#right-column').html("").load(window.location.hash.substr(2) + '.html');},400);
    }

    window.onload=(function() {
         "use strict";
         loadcontent();
        if(window.location.hash)
        {
            setTimeout(function () { $("body").find("#close").fadeIn(); },1000);
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click","nav ul li a", function (event) { 
        "use strict";
        var $clickedElement = $(event.target);
        if($clickedElement.hasClass('dropdown'))
        {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }
        else
        {
            jQuery("body").find("#loading").fadeIn();
            loadcontent();
            setTimeout(function () { $("body").find("#close").fadeIn(); },1000); 
            setTimeout(function () {jQuery("body").find("#loading").fadeOut() },2000);
        }
    });

    $("body").find("#close").click(function (){ 
      "use strict";
      window.location.hash = '';
      $("body").find("#close").hide();
      $("body").find("#right-column").find("#page-box").removeClass('fadeInDownBig').addClass('fadeOutRightBig');
      if ($(window).width() < 800) { 
      $("body").find('#right-column').html("");
      }
      else{
      setTimeout(function () { $("body").find('#right-column').html(""); },1000);
      }  

      return false;    
    });
```

Comment: You mean you need to know how to use ajax for this purpose.

Comment: @Adeel yes can you please help me out cause I tried a few things and it didn't work

Comment: Can you show the complete code. ?

Comment: See the function in my post. It is working fine if I only do it in simple HTML but when I am trying to integrade the whole thing in CODEIGNITER and it is searching in the URL fro #!about controller which it doesn't exist.. That's the problem. So maybe I have to rewrite the function but I don't have an idea how @Adeel

Comment: I can't see #!about in the code above , well you would have to modify your code in this case because !#about cannot be a controller call , it has to be <b>about</b> only. So that it calls the controller about in your controllers which will perform further tasks.